# Hawtio (in Apache Karaf) does not work with proxy

Tags: apache-karaf, hawtio

I use Apache Karaf with Hawtio. When I connect via hostname and port, then hawtio application works fine. But when I try to use Apache Karaf with proxy (for example, https://api.example.com/server/) and try to access hawtio in the following url https://api.example.com/server/hawtio then application automatically redirects to https://api.example.com/hawtio which does not exist. Seems hawtio works only with predefined context as http(s)://server:port/hawtio.

Is there a possibility to configure it to work with proxy and different context? Maybe this configuration should be done in Apache Karaf?

Thanks in advance,